# Optimization of a function with 3D bound in scipy

Tags: python, scipy, scipy-optimize

this is part of a code that I have written to optimize it in ***scipy***. I faced an error that I do not know how can I manage it. The problem is that length of `x0` is different from bounds.
Now I get an error when I run it since the length of x0 and Bounds are not the same. Indeed the shape of `x0` is = `[wt,wd,ws]` while `Bounds=[wt,wd,ws,2]`;

I must put 2 because the range of `bound` is `(0,1)` so when I want to create bound I need to put 2. so it causes to not having the same length for x0 and bounds. now I want to know that how can I solve it?

```
wt = 9 # for V80  
wd=360
ws=23
x0 = np.ones((wt,wd,ws))  # initial value for c

b=((0,1),)
bounds=np.full((wt,wd,ws),b)

res = minimize(simResult, x0=x0, bounds=bounds)
```

Answer (score 0):

Please have a closer look at the [documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.minimize.html) of `scipy.optimize.minimize` where it states that `x0` is an array of shape `(n, )` and bounds is a sequence of `(min, max)` values. If handed as array this means an array of shape `(n, 2)`.

From the documentation:

> **x0: ndarray, shape (n,)**
> Initial guess. Array of real elements of size (n,), where ‘n’ is the number of independent variables.

So you have to flatten the arrays `bounds` and `x0` accordingly to be able to pass it to `scipy.optimize.minimize`:

```py
wt = 9 # for V80  
wd=360
ws=23
x0 = np.ones((wt,wd,ws)).reshape(-1)  # initial value for c

b=((0,1),)
bounds=np.full((wt,wd,ws),b).reshape(-1, 2)
res = minimize(simResult, x0=x0, bounds=bounds)
```

The argument of the function `SimResult` must be a 1D-vector, inside the function you are free to reshape into a 3D array again though.

Again from the documentation:

> **fun: callable**
> The objective function to be minimized.
> `fun(x, *args) -> float`
> where x is an 1-D array with shape (n,) and args is a tuple of the fixed parameters needed to completely specify the function.

Here is a generic example of such a reshaping:

```py
def SimResult(x: np.ndarray):
    x_3d = x.reshape(wt,wd,ws)
    # Do calculations with x_3d...
    return result
```

Comment: sorry, but I did not get your point. now I have 3d matrix for x0 and also bounds must be 3d, with the same length of x0. since we have to define for each element of x0 a bound? Am I right? but I get errors if I do this.

Comment: See the updated post. Long story short:  You just cannot plainly pass 3D arrays to the function minimized with this function. But the workaround is easy.